# Include page with variables

Tags: php, url, include

I'm fairly new to PHP. I have learned how to use "include" to include HTML and PHP files into my PHP page. However I'm trying to include a PHP page and pass variables to it at the same time. My initial try was this:

```
include 'localhost/blah/test.php?var1=20&var2=30';
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Warning: include(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blah\index.php on line 78
```

I'm guessing that include only allows me to open a file, and not a URL. I've done some search on google and found that if allow_url_fopen is ON in my php.ini file then I should be able to do this. I checked the php.ini and it is indeed set to on.

EDIT FOLLOWING ANSWERS AND COMMENTS:

Then it seems what I want to do will not work in this way. Eventually this is what I would like:

On index.php, when user clicks on LINK_A, reload only #DIV_FOO with blah.php?var=A.

If user clicks LINK_B, reload only #DIV_FOO with blah.php?var=B.

My page is massive and I'm trying to limit the load by only having to request a "subpage" at a time, instead of requesting the whole big index.php. How would you suggest doing that?

To add to my previous comment in a bit clearer: index.php will include blah.php. If user clicks a link, I don't want index.php to be reloaded, but only blah.php changed to blah.php?var=A. Hope you understand me...

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for wanting to do this? eg is it for templating? With a bit more understanding we might be able to suggest a better solution (eg maybe a function will make your code cleaner)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can include external files by URL you still won't be able to pass variables to it as part of the URL - PHP doesn't execute the code it includes at inclusion time - just when the program flow gets to it.

However, there's no need. Included code receives the scope in which it is included, so you can declare your variables, then include your code and your included code will have access to the declared variables:

**main.php**

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
include("extra.php");
?>
```

**extra.php**

```
<?php
$c = $a * $b;
echo $c;       // 50
?>
```

Comment: Then it seems what I want to do will not work in this way. Eventually this is what I would like: On index.php, when user clicks on LINK_A, reload only #DIV_FOO with blah.php?var=A. If user clicks LINK_B, reload only #DIV_FOO with blah.php?var=B. My page is massive and I'm trying to limit the load by only having to request a "subpage" at a time, instead of requesting the whole big index.php. Not sure if I'm expressing myself correctly but if you understand what I'm saying, how would you suggest doing that?

Comment: To add to my previous comment in a bit clearer: index.php will include blah.php. If user clicks a link, I don't want index.php to be reloaded, but only blah.php changed to blah.php?var=A. Hope you understand me...

Comment: If you want to change just a portion of the page then you'll need Javascript and AJAX to do it on the client-side. If you really want PHP to do it then you'll have to reload index.php, but you could use a querystring variable and include files conditionally, based on that. For example `index.php?page=1`, then in index.php `if ($_GET['page'] == 1) {include("page1.php");}` etc.

Comment: I've managed to find a solution using iframes. When I click a link a target the iframe, only the iframe reloads to the new page. It seems to work for me. Is this a good solution in general for doing this? Seems much easier than using Javascript or AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

no need to parse the variables, just define as 'normal

```
$var1=20;
$var2=30;

include '/PATH/test.php';
```

and don't parse an external file if its hosted locally

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to include fully qualified domain name

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

```
 // Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
 // local filesystem.
 include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

 // Works.
 include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you include some file to current script all variables will such as in base script. Remeber, then you include files and working with object variables, this will not works.